# From MySQL database show an item by id

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
INSERT INTO `echipe` (`id`, `nume_echipa`, `victorii`, `infrangeri`, `steag`) VALUES
(1, 'Trencin', 0, 0, '/img/Trencin.png'),
(2, 'Astra', 0, 0, '/img/Astra.png');
```

so I want to do something like that

Astra vs Trencin but to get specify id from table and display name and other info.

My php script

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pariuri");
// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
    }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM echipe");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['nume_echipa'];
    echo "<br>";
    }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: I want to display only the id but same time to manipulate them something like I have 50 teams I want id 45 vs id 2 and display info...

Comment: SELECT * FROM echipe where id = '2';

Comment: please read again :D I edit the comment

Comment: what do you mean when you say id 45 vs id 2 ? Do you have any example of what you are trying to implement ?

Comment: i have 50 items in database id 1 to 50 right? id 50 have a name and other info and same for 47. and I want to display only this 2 items 50 and 47 how I do?

Comment: SELECT * FROM echipe where id in ('50', '47'). Does this work ?

Comment: Yes that is one match but if I have more matchs with other ids like id 5 vs id 10; id 34 vs id 20 and so on?

Comment: then you change your query accordingly? I don't know what you mean by a "match" here. Like I said, if you could provide an example of what you are trying to do then that would be helpful...

Comment: I have a database with football teams like 50ths then I want to do a page with football matches, here I have diferent ids for each team and I want to display more matches. How I do select each id from database for each match in php?

Comment: Have you considered using a dropdown list to create a 2 column "team comparison" page? Something like this maybe: http://www.cars.com/go/compare/modelCompare.jsp?myids=14897,13959 ?

Comment: yes something like that

Answer (score 0):

using raw mysqli

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pariuri");
// check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM echipe WHERE id = ?";
$stm = $con->prepare($sql) or trigger_error($con->error."[$sql]");
$stm->bind_param('s', $id);
$stm->execute();
$stm->bind_result($nume_echipa);
$stm-fetch();

echo $id, $nume_echipa;
```

using raw PDO

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pariuri;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM echipe WHERE id = ?";
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($id));
$row = $stm->fetchColumn();

echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['nume_echipa'];
```

using [safeMysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)

```
include 'safemysql.class.php';
$db = new Safemysql(array('db' => 'pariuri'));

$sql = "SELECT * FROM echipe WHERE id = ?i";
$row = $db->getRow($sql, $id)

echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['nume_echipa'];
```

Comment: please see question comments I write there more details.

Comment: My code assuming $id variable as one contains desired record's id. You may populate it whatever way you wish